# Robotframework [Return]

Tags: return, robotframework

```
Check AppData Count
${count}=    Get Text    css:mycssLocator
Log    ${count}
[Return]    ${count}
```

I am trying to get a count from a css locator and then return the text for use in other keywords, however I'm not sure that my syntax is working correctly.

When I try and use ${count} in a subsequent keyword, it isn't found - I understood [Return] as making the return available outside the keyword scope?

Comment: Please show how you are calling the keyword

Comment: Sure - any next call, like `Log   ${count}`

Comment: That's not showing how you are calling the keyword.

Answer (score 1):

You must save the value returned by a keyword if you want to use it later.

For example:

```
${count}=  check appdata count
log  count: ${count}
```